# Convert string = dataTable variable Name to DataTable type in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Im using VB.net and I have a variable that contains a string which is the name of another variable. I want to access that variable based off of that string. The scenario goes like this

I am doing a log DataTable with variable name "LogChanges"

Now I have a DataTable variable name "dtbEmployee"
the value "dtbEmployee" will be stored in DataTable "LogChanges" as string

Now 
while i loop through the "LogChanges" DataTable and get the "dtbEmployee" in string. Is there a way to use this string to point back to the "dtbEmployee" DataTable

Something like this

```
    For Each dr As DataRow In LogChanges.Select("", "DtbId")
        If dr.Item("RecordSeQ") > 0 Then
            Dim tempDataTable As DataTable
            tempDataTable = "Convert dr.Item("dtbNAme")"  to DataTable code          
        End If
    Next
```

Note: RecordSEQ is just a counter to see how many records have been modified for this table

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the `DataTable` against that name somewhere, e.g. the `Tables` collection of a `DataSet` or a `Dictionary`.  If the variable is a field and you have the object that has the correct `DataTable` assigned to that field then you could use Reflection but that would be cumbersome at best.  The variable is not the `DataTable` so you have to some actual relationship to use to get the `DataTable` via the use of the name.

Comment: can you provide an example? I don't really understand what you say. I am a new programmer to VB .NET.